# In android how to swipe screens with image buttons?

Tags: android, swipe

I want to create an android application..Where I have 3 xml files. 1st one is the splash screen, 2nd one describes the overview third one is the about me..

```
My requirement is in the page there will be three circles in the bottom for 3 screens.
when i click to a screen(swipe) it will go to another screen and one of the circle will fill up a colour.other wise 
it will blank..
```

Actually I want like :--- [This image](https://0.s3.envato.com/files/15990990/Screenshots/pic1.jpg)
 This image has 5 circles for 5 screens..if we are in page3 then 3rd no circle will fill up a colour  others will empty..

Please give me some suggestion..how can I do that????

Comment: Duplicate Question. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the ViewPager to swipe and for circle indictor you can use the image views with selectors background and manage this in onPageChangeListener.**

One of  the best and standard solution/example you can find here :
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

I have used this and working fine. please let me know if you are having any further issue.

For main screen xml You have to use FrameLayout as the images(circle indicators) will be on the top of the screens.

Comment: Ok..Actually I want "http://codecanyon.net/theme_previews/1382757-page-indicator-for-viewpager?url_name=page-indicator-for-viewpager"
that type of screens

Comment: You can acheive this using this solution, First of all you have to create a main xml such that ViewPager widget will be on full screen and three circle type image view will be on bottom and top of the viewPager, You can acehive this using the FrameLayout.

Comment: then open the link and follow the tutorial as its from android developer and it is standard and best solution